# nuxtjs route map in order

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have an issues with nuxtjs route naming.
Ex: my pages folder is
`page:
  -|blog:
     -|_categorySlug.vue
     -|_postSlug.html.vue
  -|service:
     -|index.vue`

When i access url like

example.com/blog/demo-post-slug.html -> route map to /blog/_categorySlug.vue

example.com/blog/demo-category-slug -> route map to /blog/_categorySlug.vue

Because _categorySlug.vue place in the first order inside dir blog.

When i change the file name _postSlug.html.vue to _aPostSlug.html.vue to make it become the first order.

`page:
  -|blog:
    -|_aPostSlug.html.vue
    -|_categorySlug.vue
  -|service:
    -|index.vue`

It's all right but the file naming isn't good. Anyone can give me an suggestion for this?
Thanks!